# Xamarin Forms - android issue in redirect to page, display blank page

Tags: redirect, android-intent, push-notification

I have created the intent to redirect to the page ( Basically while clicking the Notification message need to display the Review page)

**Project structure**

Xamarin Project

- ReviewPage (Content page)

Xamarin.Android Project

- ReviewActivity (create an activity class to redirect to the review page)

Xamarin Android Class project

- ManageNotification.cls

**ManageNotification.cls -->**

```
intent.SetClassName(context.ApplicationInfo.PackageName, "ReviewActivity");
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 8923, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

**In ReviewActivity -->**

```
public class ReviewActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        var page = new ReviewPage();
        var app = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current as App;
        app.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
        
    }
}
```

Is it possible to redirect to the page without calling activity?

**Issue**
I am getting a blank page and after clicking the back button I can see the ReviewPage.

**What to Achieve**
While clicking the notification message need to redirect to the ReviewPage